# How to check if contact has ever opened specific EXM email?

Tags: xdb, exm, rules-engine

I am using Sitecore 8.2 initial release and EXM 4.0.0 rev. 161028 for it.

I am creating an engagement plan and I want to create a rule condition which would say "Has contact opened email with specific EXM messageId". How can I do that?

I can see there is a page event "Email Opened"
[image: default email opened event]

But does it register the messageId?

I can also see that EXM creates an engagement plan for each message and there are states "Message Opened" and "Message Unopened".

[image]

I can check if the contact is not in "Message Unopened" state for this message plan, but I guess that is the weird way to do it.

Did anyone implement that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to implement anything. You already have what you need.

First, enable Engagement Automation for the Rules Engine group you need it for. I'm going to show you Conditional Renderings.

[image]

After this, you can use the built-in rule.

[image]

Point it to your "Message Opened" state that you mentioned, and you're good to go.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing, but I think that is not very good way to go... Will keep it for now.

Comment: @VolodymyrHil as Mark pointed out you should point it to the "Message Opened" instead of checking the contact is not in "Message Unopened" state. Seems a straight forward approach.

Comment: You don't seem to read what I'm trying to say :) 
First, pointing to 'Message Opened' is incorrect because if contact opens the email and then does some action it will be moved to next state which is 'Clicked Through Message'. So my variant with using "Message Unopened" state works better (I can negate the condition).
Second, I still think this is not good approach for checking this condition.

But it seems to work, and I will keep it for now.

Comment: You can combine it differently then. First use "where the current user is in any state in the specific engagement plan (point to your message plan" AND "except where the current is in the [message unopened] state in the specific engagement plan".